# MySQL SUM values of difference between two columns

Tags: mysql, sum, difference

I have two columns in one of my tables called TIME_OUT and TIME_IN.  These are both decimal values.  I basically want to sum the difference of these columns.  I have the query below that outputs the difference with no issue, but I'd like to then SUM the difference:

```
SELECT (TIME_IN-TIME_OUT) AS DIFF FROM TABLE_timelogs WHERE YEAR(LOG_DATE) = YEAR(NOW());

+------+
| DIFF | 
+------+
| 10.0 |
|  4.0 |
|  3.0 |
+------+
```

Is there a way to integrate SUM into the query so that the ultimate output is 17.0?  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add SUM to your query so the query reads:

```
SELECT SUM(TIME_IN-TIME_OUT) AS DIFF 
FROM TABLE_timelogs 
WHERE YEAR(LOG_DATE) = YEAR(NOW());
```

This adds the contents of the column 'diff'.

Comment: Wow - that was easy and did the trick!  Thank you for the help!!

Comment: I have posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62608035/mysql-show-sum-of-difference-of-two-values)  related to it can you please see it?