# MySQL show sum of difference of two values

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum, window-functions

Below is my query.

```
SELECT n.`name`,n.`customer_id`,m.`msn`, m.kwh,
   m.kwh - LAG(m.kwh) OVER(PARTITION BY n.`customer_id` ORDER BY m.`data_date_time`) AS kwh_diff
FROM mdc_node n
INNER JOIN `mdc_meters_data` m ON n.`customer_id` = m.`cust_id`
WHERE n.`lft` = 5 AND n.`icon` NOT IN ('folder')
AND m.`data_date_time` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
```

Which gives me below result

[image]

I want to sum up the `kwh_diff` and to show only one-row record not multiple like below

`name      customer_id      msn            sum_kwh_diff`

`Zeeshan   37010114711      4A60193390663  4.5`

I have tried to do the following

```
 SUM(m.kwh - LAG(m.kwh) OVER(PARTITION BY n.`customer_id` ORDER BY m.`data_date_time`)) AS sum_kwh_diff
```

and got `Error Code: 4074 Window functions can not be used as arguments to group functions.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to sum the differences between consecutive rows.
Say, for example, that you have these values for the column `kwh`:

```
kwh
---
10
12
14
17
25
32
```

so the differences are:

```
kwh_diff
--------
0
12-10
14-12
17-14
25-17
32-25
```

The sum of these differences is equal to `32-10` which is:

> the diffference between the last value and the first value

So what you need is window function `FIRST_VALUE()` to obtain these values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.`name`, n.`customer_id`, m.`msn`, 
   FIRST_VALUE(m.kwh) OVER (PARTITION BY n.`customer_id` ORDER BY m.`data_date_time` DESC) -
   FIRST_VALUE(m.kwh) OVER (PARTITION BY n.`customer_id` ORDER BY m.`data_date_time` ASC) AS kwh_diff
FROM mdc_node n
INNER JOIN `mdc_meters_data` m ON n.`customer_id` = m.`cust_id`
WHERE n.`lft` = 5 AND n.`icon` NOT IN ('folder')
AND m.`data_date_time` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
```

and no subquery or aggregation is needed.

I kept in my code `PARTITION BY n.customer_id` because you use it in your code, although you may need `PARTITION BY n.customer_id, m.msn`.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t use window functions within an aggregate function (while the opposite is possible), Here, you need to use a subquery, and aggregate in the outer query:

```
SELECT name, customer_id, SUM(kwh_diff) sum_kwh_diff
FROM (
    SELECT n.`name`,n.`customer_id`,m.`msn`, m.kwh,
       m.kwh - LAG(m.kwh) OVER(PARTITION BY n.`customer_id` ORDER BY m.`data_date_time`) AS kwh_diff
    FROM mdc_node n
    INNER JOIN `mdc_meters_data` m ON n.`customer_id` = m.`cust_id`
    WHERE n.`lft` = 5 AND n.`icon` NOT IN ('folder')
    AND m.`data_date_time` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
) t
GROUP BY name, customer_id
```

Answer (score 2):

MAke an outer Query

```
SELECT
`name`,`customer_id`,`msn`, SUM(kwh_diff) kwh_diff
FROM
(
    SELECT n.`name`,n.`customer_id`,m.`msn`, m.kwh,
       m.kwh - LAG(m.kwh) OVER(PARTITION BY n.`customer_id` ORDER BY m.`data_date_time`) AS kwh_diff
    FROM mdc_node n
    INNER JOIN `mdc_meters_data` m ON n.`customer_id` = m.`cust_id`
    WHERE n.`lft` = 5 AND n.`icon` NOT IN ('folder')
    AND m.`data_date_time` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW() ) t1
GROUP BY `name`,`customer_id`,`msn`
```